# Скачивание файла через GuzzleHttp

Tags: php, guzzle

```
$path = "https://..../data.csv";

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;

$response = $client->get($path, [
    "sink" => "tmp/result.csv", 
    "allow_redirects" => false
]);
```

Как сделать, чтобы при скачивании (записи результата) в файл `tmp/result.csv` ничего не записывалось, если статус запроса не равен `200`? Сейчас записывается пустой ответ..

Comment: `$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.github.com/repos/guzzle/guzzle');

if ($response->getStatusCode() == 200) { ... }` __?__

Comment: @Эдуард, в этом случае нужно делать 2 запросы, 1 - проверку статуса, 2 - получение данных для записи в файл.

В параметр `"sink"` передается конечный путь, куда будет записан ответ. Вопрос в том, можно ли каким-то колбэком или еще как-то записывать ответ при условии, что статус 200?

Comment: Если одним запросом не получится, как вариант можно удалить или очистить tmp/result.csv при не успешном ответе